# button click is not working

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, html

i am having a button on a modal pop up div. But i am not getting the click event of the button. I am calling this button inside a gridview. Whenever i call it outside the gridview it works perfect, but whenver i call it inside that gridview, it does not work. The popup window appears and disappears as desired buyt the click event of a button on it is not working. following is my code for calling javascript function from the javascript class.

```
lbtnReload.Attributes.Add("onclick", "SingleUpload('" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "')");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this .... mention `javascript`

```
lbtnReload.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:SingleUpload('" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "')");
```